# use of the DWORD_PTR

Tags: c++, dword

What is the use of the DWORD_PTR in the following function

```
/*static*/ int FRCPACKAGE::ByHash(FRCPACKAGE* frcpackage1, FRCPACKAGE* frcpackage2, DWORD_PTR)
{return _tcsicmp(frcpackage2->Hash(), frcpackage1->Hash());}
```

Comment: Obfuscation.  It's so that you have to search through tons of documentation in order to know what type you need to pass to the function.

Answer (score 1):

It's an extra parameter of type `DWORD_PTR` (probably a typedef to an `unsigned long *` or something similar), but because it's not used in the function, it's not given a name. That way, most compilers won't issue an "unused parameter" warning.